# Django User Login Not Working

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-login

Django User login not working when i tried to login from a view different than the view i used to authenticate the user.

Q1) What are the values of the object "user" in `login(request,user)`  ?

Q2) I want to login from a different view other than the view i check for authentication,How can i implement this ?

Q3) When i does i am getting an 'unicode' object has no attribute 'pk' ERROR.I tried

ulogin view

```
def ulogin(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    error=0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username'].lower()
        password = request.POST['pwd']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user==None:
        error= "Invalid login details"
        return render_to_response('login.html', {'error' :error}, context)

    elif login_check(username)==0 :    # from Modules.py 

        error= "Enter OTP sent to your e-mail, registered "
        return render_to_response('otp.html', {'error' :error,'u':user}, context)
```

otp.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/ulogin/{{u}}/otp" method="POST">
```

..

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

otp view

```
def otp(request,user):
   context = RequestContext(request)
   error=False
   current_user = User.objects.get(username=user)
   users=UserProfile.objects.get(user=current_user)
   if users.OTP==request.POST['otp']:
      login(request,user)
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
      error=True
      return render_to_response('otp.html', {'OTPerror' :error}, context)
```

ERROR

```
AttributeError
```

Exception Value:
'unicode' object has no attribute 'pk'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to use `login(request, user)` without authentication (). login is always followed by an authenticate(). You have to restrict it first